# How do you add a background image to your header in CSS

Tags: image, debugging, background

I am trying to add a background image to my header from my files, but it is not working. Other images from online work, but the images from my files don't.

I have tried adding more information about the position of the images I have tried changing the image file from jpeg to gif, and back again. here is my code I will attach the html with it as well.

```
.header { 
    background: url("BestChessHeader.jpg"), left top repeat;
    padding: 20px;

}
h1 {
  
  text-shadow: 2px 2px blue;
}type here
```

that is the css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="BestChess.css">
<title> BestChess </title>
<div class="header">
<h1>BestChess</h1>
</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Puzzles</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
</nav>

<div class="column">
</div>
```

and here is the html.

everything works it's just the background image I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: I have figured it out. I just needed to specify the image path. background-image does not work. background does.

Answer (score 0):

You can add background-image instead of background only.

`background-image: url('./Chartjs.png')`